# Get triggered rule names which is executing on decision server from client side (Redhat Decision Manager)

Tags: drools, redhat, kie, redhat-brms

I am using the REST api for executing rules on Decision Server (Redhat Decision Manager 7.2) using a stateless kie session. I'm currently getting the number of triggered rules, but I also want to get the names of those rules. Is this possible?

```
KieServicesConfiguration conf = KieServicesFactory.newRestConfiguration(URL, USER, PASSWORD);

List<GenericCommand<?>> commands = new ArrayList<GenericCommand<?>>();

commands.add((GenericCommand<?>)
KieServices.Factory.get().getCommands().newInsert(applicant, "applicant"));

commands.add((GenericCommand<?>)
KieServices.Factory.get().getCommands().newInsert(loan, "loan"));

commands.add((GenericCommand<?>)KieServices.Factory.get().getCommands().newFireAllRules("numberOfFiredRules"));

KieCommands kieCommands = KieServices.Factory.get().getCommands();

BatchExecutionCommand batchCommand = kieCommands.newBatchExecution(commands, "default-stateless-ksession");

ServiceResponse<ExecutionResults> executeResponse = ruleServicesClient
                .executeCommandsWithResults("loan-application_1.2.0", batchCommand);

System.out.println("Number of fired rules:" executeResponse.getResult().getValue("numberOfFiredRules"));
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to use an AgendaEventListener to keep track of rules exectioned. By implemnting [org.kie.api.event.rule.AgendaEventListener](https://github.com/kiegroup/droolsjbpm-knowledge/blob/master/kie-api/src/main/java/org/kie/api/event/rule/AgendaEventListener.java) interface you can capture these detials.

Comment: I am executing rules on the Decision Server, I have only serverUrl, containerName and BatchExecutionCommand. I dont have **KieSession** so ı dont able to do `kSession.addEventListener(new DefaultAgendaEventListener() { ...}`. Can you explain ı dont geti it.

Comment: If you are using Decision-server for rule execution then you have to add custom AgendaListener class in classpath of kie-server.war file and register listener in kie-deployment-descriptor.xml file under eventListener tag

Comment: Listener will capture details at server side. There is no way we can get details about executed rules at client side

Answer (score 0):

To know which rules are triggered I added an action column with custom code (Action BRL fragment) that writes the rule name in one of the field of my fact. You can get it from `rule.name`.
Example:`myFact.logMyRuleName(rule.name)`